# Mangento and CCAvenue

Tags: php, magento, ccavenue

I would like to know which latest version of Mangento is compatible with CCAvenue gateway. And can you also point out a tutorial on how to implement the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if u figured it out or not. But I am not sure about the significance of this question.
First of all people are using CCAVENE with magento from V1.3. We are also using it with Magento 1.5.
If u request to ccavanue payment gateway integration team they will give u a module that will be ready to use.
Hope u can get that module & get that running